# Method or data member not found when executing Application.Screenupdating?

Tags: vba, excel

I button calls the following procedure:

```
Sub ImportData()
    Dim currentCalculationMethod As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    currentCalculationMethod = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Call ClearData
    Call LoopFiles

    Sheets("Start").Activate

    Application.Calculation = currentCalculationMethod        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

All of the sudden I am getting an error message that "method or data member not found" and the VBE highlights `.ScreenUpdating = False` for me. What could be the problem that is causing this?

I am running Excel 2013.

This problem does not seem to exist in other files. I don't know what has happened in this file that is causing this.

EDIT:

When I try to run:

```
Sub GetFolder()
    Dim f As Office.FileDialog
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With f
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("folderPath") = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

then I get the same error message and Excel highlights `.FileDialog`.

Comment: This can happen if the active application is not *Excel* ..................does your macro activate another application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what caused the problem. I had another module that was named `application`. I guess Excel didn't like this. I can understand that but would have hoped for better guidance by the VBE.